# How to break a long fraction numerator?

Tags: equations

I have this long equation and using `split` or `aligned` is not helping. How do I wrap it and how do I make sure thatRHS of the eqn is always on the right side of equal to ('=') even when line is changed?

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
\rho'(x_1,x'_1,x_2,x'_2)=
\exp[-\frac{u^2(x_2-x'_2)^2}{4a^2}]\int_{\mathbb{R}}
\exp[-\frac{(1+R^4)(x_2-y)^2+(x_2-y)(2x_1-2R^4x_1)+(x'_2-y)^2(1+R^4)+(x'_2-y)
(2x'_1-2R^4x'_1)+x_1^2(1+R^4)+x'^2_1(1+R^4)}{4R^2}]\exp[-\frac{a^2y^2}{\nu^2}]
  dy
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: with either `split` or `aligned`, you have to indicate where line breaks should go, with `\\ `, and you also need to specify an alignment point in each line, with `&`.  in the first line, the `&` should go before the `=` sign, and on subsequent lines, the `&` should be at the beginning, with some space (often `\qquad`) immediately after the `&` to indent these lines a bit farther to the right than the `=`.  it wouldn't hurt to read the `amsmath` documentation; `texdoc amsmath` at a command line prompt if you are working on a system based on tex live.

Comment: The problem is the integral, I cant use \\ inside the intergal!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

I would do it with `geometry`, in the first place, to have a decent text width, then with `\splitfrac` command from `mathtools`, and the `\medmath` command from `nccmath` (makes formulae  ~ 80 % of `\displaystyle`) and finally `\bigints` to have an appropriate integral sign:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[show frame]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath, bigints, amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \intertext{$ \rho'(x₁,x'₁,x₂,x'₂)=
      \exp\biggl[-\frac{u²(x₂-x'₂)²}{4a²}\biggr] × $}
  \bigintsss_{\mathbb{R}}\exp\left[-\frac{\medmath{\splitfrac{(1+R⁴)(x₂-y)²+(x₂-y)(2x₁-2R⁴x₁)+(x'₂-y)²(1+R⁴)}{+(x'₂-y)
          (2x'₁-2R⁴x'₁)+x₁²(1+R⁴)+x'²₁(1+R⁴)}}}{4R^{2\strut}}\right]\exp\biggl[-\frac{a²y²}{\nu²}\biggr]
  dy
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]